# How to pass information from one app and show it in another app using startupFcn(app) method in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two apps that I designed using app designer 2016b, the the first interface is a login screen that takes the username and the password and has a login button, when the login button is pressed the second app appears which should have the username that the user typed in the login interface.

The problem that I am having is that I am not able to show the username in the second app using startupFcn(app) method, it only shows if I put the code in button callback which I don't want.

Here is that code that I used in the login in to send the data:

```
 function LOGINButtonPushed(app, event)
v = app.EditField_2.Value;
y = v;
g = MainInterface;
g.Data = y;
close(gcbf);
```

And here is the code of the second app which is suppose to retrieve the username and put it in a label:

```
function startupFcn(app)
results = app.Data;
set(app.UsernameLabel,'text',results);
```